# Keyboard keys being remapped in some application

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, remapping

At least once a week one of my applications gets all screwed up and typing with the keyboard becomes impossible. Today it's an email in Outlook, last week it was AbstractSpoon's ToDoList. I was writing my email completely fine two minutes ago, then I did some surfing, came back to my email and now most of my keys are remapped to something else.

When it happens, it only affects that specific application instance, and every other application still works fine. And if I close and reopen Outlook then everything's hunky-dory again.

Examples:

`qwertyuiop` produces `azertyuiop`

`1234567890` produces `&é"'(-è_çà`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid Windows. I looked in the Regional Settings bit of Control Panel and there's a keyboard shortcut there to switch between languages, it's set to Left Alt+Shift for some reason (???).

So I must have pressed that shortcut and it switched to the French language. I pressed it again in Outlook and it's now back to normal again \o/

I turned that shortcut off and it should never happen again (touch wood).

Comment: Guess you answered your own question! Nice to know there is a shortcut for that though!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can say, this maps a french keyboard: we have to caps lock for numbers, as opposed to english, and é, è, ç and à are typical french keys. Also I think we are the only ones to use azerty keyboards...

What OS are you running? I have seen it before with windows XP that the keyboard mapping would just change all of a sudden to something else. Also, in Leopard for instance, changing a keyboard mapping only affects the one application I am currently working on, and not the other ones until I reboot.

Do you have any language bar displayed, that you can change your keyboard setting easily?